# Regex for replacing 10th comma-separated column in CSV file

Tags: regex, csv, sublimetext

I have some files containing tens of thousand of rows of the format:

```
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10
```

I want to replace `value10` with a certain number (say `x`). So the result should be:

```
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, x
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, x
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, x
```

I want to do this with regex. I have Sublime Text as a text editor.

Comment: Would be very nice, if the title would have nth of included and comma separated not like (comma-separated) for better searchability

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
^((?:[^,]+,\s*){9})[^,]+
```

And replace using:

```
$1x
```

`((?:[^,]+,\s*){9})` will match and group first 9 comma separated values that you can use in back-reference `$1`. `[^,]+` outside parenthesis will match 10th value to be replaced.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kN5uS9/1)

PS: Verified that back-reference works in `Sublime Test 3` as well.

Comment: This find the first such value, but say I have multiple rows. See for example https://regex101.com/r/kN5uS9/4

Comment: Thank you!

However, it seems to matter that the values are decimal numbers, for example. Has it something do to with the dot?
https://regex101.com/r/kN5uS9/7

Comment: [It actually works](https://regex101.com/r/kN5uS9/8) As you note I have `\s*` in my answer not `\s+` as you had.

Comment: It worked! I am very grateful, this will shave off hours of selecting things manually. Question is resolved.

Comment: In Sublime Text 3, this is incorrect - this does not match the item at the 10th index, it matches all items up to the 9th index (inclusive).  I am also not sure if the find/replace with backreferences is an implemented feature of Sublime Text 3 - it does not appear to work in v3.1.1 Build 3176.

Comment: To reproduce, just create a dummy CSV with five columns, CTRL+SHIFT+F, click the Regex button, and find `^((?:[^,]+,\s*){3})[^,]+`. This will match everything leading up to the index, inclusive.  This is almost right - from there, the user could (in theory) use Sublime Text 3's multi-select features to then select the items at the n+1th indices, but if the CSV contains spaces or anything like that, then this approach is not always reliable.

Comment: Of course - that's what I meant by "click the Regex button" :)

Comment: Yep - confirmed that this does work as described.  I was confused initially because the regex does not match the indicated values exactly.  I will remove the downvote.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
^(?:[^,]+,\s*){9}\K[^,]+
```

You can use `\K` to discard `9` matches and then replace `10th`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/kN5uS9/3

[image]

Comment: Ah, okay - I see what's going on.  The regex you posted (`(?m)^(?:[^,]+,\s+){3}\K[^,]+`) is custom-tailed for the OP's CSV file, where each value has a leading space.  This is not always the case.  `(?m)^(?:[^,]+,){3}\K[^,]+` will work if the CSV values do not have leading spaces.

Comment: The regex you provided will *only* work under very specific circumstances (when the user has a CSV whose values have leading spaces).

Comment: No need - as I have stated above, your answer is correct if you remove the `\s+`.  This removes the assumption that the user's CSV values have one or more leading spaces.

Comment: Because the provided regex makes incorrect assumptions about the content of the CSV in question, I did not find this answer useful.  Of course, if you were to edit the answer to work for more CSVs (by removing the `\s+` or changing it to `\s*`), I would remove the downvote.